# Jquery form validation before Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have gone through other threads and used one for reference but still I am not able to find the solution.
  My question is:

I am calling a function on button click now that function has validation after validation I am trying to post data with ajax request in submit handler, problem is my fields are getting verified but Ajax request is not invoked.

```
<input type="button" value="Register" id="registerP" onclick="registerPatient()"  class="form-control input-sm btn-success ">

function registerPatient(){
$("#patientRegistration").validate({
rules: {
    patientName: {
    required: true,
    textOnly: true
                },
       },
messages: {
       patientName: {
       required: "Please enter the full name",                  
                    },
          },
submitHandler: function(form) { 
            $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/LoginMavenSpringMVC/appointment/savePatient",
             data: "patientName=" + patientName,
         success: function(response){},
         error: function(e){}
      });
  }
 });
}
```

However if I am not using validation and calling Ajax directly i am able to post the data. Please suggest where I am going Wrong.

Comment: give url or upload complete , so that can clearly look into

Comment: i dint get your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this which call jquery form validation and check if validated:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#patientRegistration").validate({
    rules: {
        patientName: {
        required: true,
        textOnly: true
                    },
           },
    messages: {
           patientName: {
           required: "Please enter the full name",                  
                        },
              }
     });
});

function registerPatient(){
   var IsValid=$("#patientRegistration").valid();
   if(IsValid){
     var patientName=""; //value for patient name
     $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/LoginMavenSpringMVC/appointment/savePatient",
             data: {"patientName": patientName},
             success: function(response){},
             error: function(e){}
     });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `data` syntax of ajax to this.

```
data: {patientName:patientName},
```

Make sure you have a parameter on catching method of the same name "patientName" to invoke its post from page on post.

This should work.

Also check if you get a patientName paramater value in your post. To do so first check by "alert" and pass the patientName parameter. You will know what you are getting and why post is not happening.

Comment: It is saving data if I am not using validation code, that is when ajax is invoked when function is called. This means with this code Ajax is not Invoked else it would have given me error in console.